# Excel, how to deactivate mailto link?

Tags: microsoft-excel, mailto

At home I use LibreOffice. When a cell contains a mail address, I can deactivate the mailto link, making it plain text, by clicking CTRL+M.
At work I'm obliged to work with Excel though and I can't find how to deactivate the mailto link in the same fashion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click and select `Remove Hyperlink`.  This will work on more than one cell at a time, if selected.

If you want prevent Excel from automatically inserting *any* hyperlinks, you can turn it off in in the AutoFormat As You Type options. In Excel 2016, these are found under File > Options > Proofing > AutoCorrect Options. Select the AutoFormat As You Type tab, then uncheck the box "Internet and network paths with hyperlinks".